# Issues logging in via Facebook

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, login, facebook

I am having timeout issues using Facebook to log in to any of the Stack Exchange sites.

I get a timeout error connection to the remote server. Is the server at stackauth.com taking too long to respond?

Comment: It's... Being fixed. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some work being done on stackauth this weekend sort of broke a redirect step.

It's been fixed, you should be able to login via Facebook now.

Comment: cheers kev thought i broke my browser for a moment +1 for quick response!